# Define commands for symbols with index, combine with accents

Tags: math-mode, macros, accents

To facilitate writing of formulas that contain symbols with subscript, I often define custom commands. However, combining these with accents gives unpleasant results. Is there any way to define such abbreviations and to still obtain the 'right' placement of accents? For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ang}{\varphi_\mathrm{example}}
\begin{document}
$\ang$ is ok, but $\dot{\ang}$ is not. I'd rather obtain $\dot{\varphi}_\mathrm{example}$ without spelling it out. How?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math accents work on the next math atom. `\dot` does not take an argument, the curly braces are generating a sub formula and the dot is placed above the sub formula. Without curly braces `\ang` is expanded and the dot is placed on `\varphi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ang}{\varphi_\mathrm{example}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb|$\dot{\ang}$| & $\dot{\ang}$ \\
  \verb|$\dot\ang$| & $\dot\ang$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Update:**

In case of package `amsmath` `\dot` and some other accents are redefined and catch its base character as argument. Then the above example will not work.
This problem can be solved by using `\expandafter`. `\ang` is expanded once. Then `\dot` sees the first token (or token group) of the definition text of `\ang`, that is `\varphi`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ang}{\varphi_\mathrm{example}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \verb|$\dot{\ang}$| & $\dot{\ang}$ \\
  \verb|$\expandafter\dot\ang$| & $\expandafter\dot\ang$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Example with amsmath]

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't work when `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With an additional `\def\Dot{\expandafter\dot}` I probably have all I need.